# Can models with experimental features be exported?

Tags: experimental-features

I was following a [guide](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/rope) to create a model of a rope, it uses some experimental features available in ver. 2.78, mainly - displacement.
What I'd like to know is whether it is possible to export a model like this, preserving the detail and if not then is there a way to preserve as much detail as possible.

I am converting my models to FBX for later use in a game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptive subdivision and micropolygon displacement are only processed at render time. They can't be exported in FBX. If you really want all that geometry, you have to use regular subdivision and a regular displacement modifier. However the level of detail used in Andrew's tutorial is unusable for a game engine. You should use the old method shown at the very begining of the video that is create 3 circles, add a screw modifier, an array and a curve modifier like this : [image]

[image]

and add a normal map to get the details.